# Defining javascript objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to create a key-value pair javascript object as follows:

```
var p={'revEv':[{'EventsId':rand, 
        if(Ext.getCmp('Val_'+id).getValue()!='E')
        'Status':Ext.getCmp('Val_'+id).getValue(),
        'core':Ext.fly('coreVal_'+id).dom.innerHTML,
        'transactionType':{'transactionTypeId':Ext.fly('oppVal_'+id).dom.innerHTML,'description':Ext.fly("oppDesc_"+id).dom.innerHTML},
        'timing':Ext.getCmp('quarter_'+id).getValue()},]}
```

As seen above, for a particular entry 'Status' - I need to create/insert the key only if a particular condition is satisfied.
What is an elegant way to do this in javascript?

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. You can't use `if` statement in object literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize everything else and then set status in an if statement:

```
var p={'revEv':[{'EventsId':rand, 
    'core':Ext.fly('coreVal_'+id).dom.innerHTML,
    'transactionType':{'transactionTypeId':Ext.fly('oppVal_'+id).dom.innerHTML,'description':Ext.fly("oppDesc_"+id).dom.innerHTML},
    'timing':Ext.getCmp('quarter_'+id).getValue()},]}

if (Ext.getCmp('Val_'+id).getValue()!='E') {
    p.revEv[0].Status = Ext.getCmp('Val_'+id).getValue(),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
var p = {};
if(condition) p.key = value;
```